# Excel, Calculate Sum of one column where the corresponding row in another column equals a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

So I have the following formula which works perfectly to calculate the SUM of an entire column of another worksheet which I reference indirectly.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A4&"!C:C"))
```

What I need now is to calculate the SUM of C (as above) but only when the relevant row in Column D is equal to Yes.

Can this be done?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean that in A4 there is the worksheet name and if there is 'Yes' in cell D4, then the sum should be evaluated?

Comment: A4 is the worksheet name - correct, Column D next to Column C in the referenced worksheet contains the Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A4&"!D:D"),"Yes",INDIRECT(A4&"!C:C"))
```